# Reply form not showing for ajax_comment module installed for Open social distribution

Tags: 8

recently I've installed Open Social Distribution and installed the ajax_comment module to enable ajax comments and reply but unfortunately the reply link never appear at the home page that shows all posts
here is a screenshot of a post showing in home page:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the issue tracker for the ajax_comments module? I think the problem lies there

Comment: where to check this?

Comment: Go to the project page on drupal.org, and click the issues link under the _Bug report_ section

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that connected user has `Post comments` Permission Or anonymous has it. 
[image]

Comment: yes it's checked for Authenticated users

Comment: Comments form is displaying correctly and comments are added properly but reply link not showing neither reply form !! this is my problem

Comment: which drupal version ?

Comment: drupal  version 8 open social distribution